# Check a set of URLs if it contains a particular table ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I have a set of URL links, some of which contains a table and some that does not return any table.

I've inspected the source and there is this particular table ID that loads at runtime. Is there a script or tool to check each URL content and see if it contains that particular table ID and return true?

I can use this script or tool to load a batch of URLs to see which URL contains the table that I am looking for.

Comment: By "table ID", do you mean `<table id="someId">` inside the html content of the URL? And are those URLs are in the same domain as the caller? If yes, you can use a loop in JS to load all URLs using ajax and regex to check the table ID. If not in the same domain, you need to create the script in php that will load that URLs (e.g. using `curl`) and check the table ID using regex.

Comment: Yes, By table id I eman inside the html content of the URL in the same domain as the caller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549150/how-to-scrap-specific-ids-from-a-webpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is web scraping. Many languages have a way to do this.
Pick what you are most comfortable with. However, Python with the [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup) library is a nice choice.