# How to scrape specific IDs from a Webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, scrape

I need to do some real estate market research and for this in need the prices, and other values from new houses.

So my idea was to go on the website where i get the information. 
Go to the Main-Search-Site and scrape all the RealEstateIDs that would navigate me directly to the single pages for each house where i can than extract my infos that i need.

My problem is how do i get all the real estate ids from the main page and store them in a list, so i can use them in the next step to build the urls with them to go to the acutal sites.

I tried it with beautifulsoup but failed because i dont understand how to search for a specific word and extract what comes after it.

The html code looks like this:

```
""realEstateId":110356727,"newHomeBuilder":"false","disabledGrouping":"false","resultlist.realEstate":{"@xsi.type":"search:ApartmentBuy","@id":"110356727","title":"
```

Since the value "realEstateId" appears around 60 times, i want to scrape evertime the number (here: 110356727) that comes after it and store it in a list, so that i can use them later.

Edit:

```
    import time
    import urllib.request
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import bs4 as bs
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import style
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    import pickle
    import requests
    from requests import get 
url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true?enteredFrom=result_list'
        response = get(url)
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        type(html_soup)

        def expose_IDs():
            resp = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true?enteredFrom=result_list')
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
            table = soup.find('resultListModel')
            tickers = []
            for row in table.findAll('realestateID')[1:]:
                ticker = row.findAll(',')[0].text
                tickers.append(ticker)
            with open("exposeID.pickle", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(tickers, f)
            return tickers

        expose_IDs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? There are 68 keys in a dictionary that are ids. I use regex to grab the same script as you are after and trim of an unwanted character, then load with `json.loads` and access the json object as shown in image at bottom.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true?enteredFrom=result_list')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0].rstrip(',')
#resultListModel: 
results = json.loads(script)
ids = list(results['searchResponseModel']['entryInformation'].keys())
print(ids)
```

Ids:

[image]

---

Since website updated:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true?enteredFrom=result_list')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0].rstrip(',')
results = json.loads(script)
ids = [item['@id'] for item in results['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries'][0]['resultlistEntry']]
print(ids)
```

Comment: hey I dont want to open a new thread and since you helped me so much last time I thought I ask You here directly.
The website changed the Html Code and "entryInformation" is not there anymore
Do You have any other solution to change the code that I still get all the ID's?

Comment: you can if it is quick. If it longer and requires code and html opening a new thread is  the better thing to do.

Comment: The website changed the Html Code and "entryInformation" is not there anymore Do You have any other solution to change the code that I still get all the ID's?

Comment: Sure. I think I can see where the new ids are

Comment: Please check edit and see if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes that works quiet code i think i dont get all IDs but 50%, Since I get problems in other areas now I'll open a new thread. 
Thanks!

Comment: One moment then please.

Comment: Can you give me a missing id value?

Comment: "111310689" for e.g. is the last one on the Page

Comment: that is in the list output It is the last one/

Comment: hey sorry for the delayed answer. Im just getting 20 IDs as output but the Page contains 60. It seems like the script stops to soon.

Comment: please provide me with a missing id found on the page but not in the answer above.

Comment: All of these for example: 
"105147583
103639187
89145037
111337199
96836280
101618556
101618055
101617574
102721369
108761945
110914846
108761466
108761117
111148131
111147712
111147267"

Comment: hey any chance to have a quick chat with you

Comment: @CosmoCramer Yes but not until this evening unless it is literally a 1 minute thing.